# Does OS have to deallocate process's heap memory?

Tags: linux, operating-system

When I searched about "What happens if malloc and exit with not free?", I could find answers saying "Today, OS will recover all the allocated memory space after a program exit".

In that answer, what is the meaning of "recover"?.
OS just delete it's PCB and page table when process exit doesn't it?
Are there additional tasks OS has to do for complete termination of process?

Comment: Well, it needs to stop all threads belonging to the process first, (possibly excepting one that will be used to run the process cleanup in kernel mode).  Those not running on cores can just be marked as 'not to run again', those running need to have their cores interrupted to force those threads to enter the kernel for the last time.  Once all user mode threads/execution has stopped, resource cleanup, eg memory, can begin.

Answer (score 2):

When a program starts, the OS allocates some memory to it. During the programs execution the program can request more blocks of memory from the OS and it can release them as well when it doesn't need them any more. When the program exits, all the memory used by it is returned to the OS.

The pair `malloc()/free()` (and their siblings and equivalents) do not interact with the OS<sup>1</sup>. They manage a block of memory (called "heap") the program already got from the OS when it was launched.

All in all, from the OS point of view it doesn't matter if your program uses `free()` or not. For the program it's important to use `free()` when a piece of memory is not needed to let further allocations succeed (by reusing the freed memory blocks).

---

<sup>1</sup> This is not entirely true. The implementation of `malloc()` may get more memory blocks from the OS to extend the heap when it is full but this process is transparent to the program. For the program's point of view, `malloc()` and `free()` operate inside a memory block that already belongs to the program.

Answer (score 2):

The operating system allocates and manages memory pages in a process. As part of the process cleanup at exit, the operating system has to deallocate the pages assigned to a process. This includes the page tables, page file space, and physical page frames mapped to logical pages. This takes is complicated because multiple processes may map to the same physical page frames which requires some form of reference counting.

The heap is just memory. The operating system has no knowledge whatsoever of process heaps. Inside malloc (and similar functions), there will be calls to operating system services to map pages to the process address space. The operating system creates the pages but does not care what the pages are used for.

If you do malloc's without corresponding free's your process will keep requesting more and more pages from the operating system (until you reach the point where the system will fail to allocate more pages). All you are doing is screwing up the heap within your own process.

When the process exits, the operating system will just get rid of the the pages allocated to the heap and your application's failure to call free will cause no problem to the system at all.

Thus, there is a two level system at work. malloc allocates bytes. The operating system allocates pages.